# how do i remove ï»¿ in golang in the beginning of a file?

Tags: go

```
func Test_Read_Unicode(t *testing.T) {
    s := "ï»¿Οὐχὶ ταὐτὰ, παρίσταταί μοι, γιγνώσκειν ὦ, ἄνδρες ᾿Αθηναῖοι\n" +
        "ὅταν τ᾿, εἰς τὰ πράγματα ἀποβλέψω, καὶ ὅταν, πρὸς τοὺς\n"

    runes := []rune(s)
```

Comment: Try reading through documentation for the [`strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package. I'm sure there's a function there that could help you; finding out *which* is left as an exercise ;-)

Comment: You encounderd byte order mark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Do you _actually_ have a double-encoded BOM in your test case? If so, then just delete it. If not, then this code snippet obviously has nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: Just cut it of via s[3:] or whatever fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

In Go package [scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/go/scanner/) can skip byte order marks.

Comment: What I am trying to do, is check runes, see if they match BOM if they do, delete if not keep them. Thanks